# React Native UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined at WebSocketServer

Tags: android, react-native, expo

My react native app is ejected from expo. I have upgraded my react native app from expo 35 to expo 36. After upgrading I am facing two issues.

1. After build app crashes with white screen on first time open by android studio, but when i click app on simulator it starts working fine.
2. After app open I am getting error in my console

   > UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined at WebSocketServer

I have looked for everything but didn't get any success.
The error is coming in web socket server inside metro package of react native 0.61

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use on that command for WebSocketServer run "node_modules.bin\jest" --init if you are on Windows.